# Are these polynomials irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Is $(x^2-1)^2+(y^2-1)^2-1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ ?

Is $(x^2-1)^2+(y^2-1)^2$ irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ ?

Comment: 1) $(y^2-1)^2-1=y^2(y-\sqrt 2)(y+\sqrt2)$ and Eisenstein.

Comment: 2) Use its decomposition in $\mathbb C[x,y]$. (Note that both polynomials you got are irreducible and not associate over $\mathbb C$.)